# Making formulas for columns in open office

Tags: excel, openoffice.org

How do you make a formula for these columns in OpenOffice. So that you only need to fill in 1 column and the others are automatically calculated and filled in. 
So it doesn't matter which column you enter the value in, the others are auto filled in for me. Thanks in advance.
 [image]

Comment: You may have better luck at SO's sister site: http://superuser.com.

Comment: I agree. Voted for migration to superuser, please do not crosspost, this question will be migrated if the community thinks it is better there than here.

Comment: Please explain how do you want the other columns to be filled. Do you mean to automatically make a ratio between week/month/year? what is your ratio? 4.5 weeks a month? 52 weeks a year? do you want to divide by 7 and multiply by 30 or 365?

Comment: I think its best to use days continuously rather than weeks. so 7 days wud be the first column the 2nd column shud be 30 days and the last column shud be 365 days. so it shud always be broken down into a per day value and then multiply backup for that column, to get the result. I just dont know how to make it work for multiple columns simultaneously. i can make it for one; but i cant make it for columns simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Cells are best used either purely for input (values) or output (formulas). Solving this in exactly the way specified is going to cause you some difficulty however you go about doing it, as you seem to be requesting a setup where the same cell can do either.

Without resorting to macros, I think the closest you can get to what you're intimating here is to populate the three cells in each column with formulas that refer to each other's values. However, excel won't like this- it will cause a circular reference error until someone types a value at least one column in each row, overwriting the formula in that cell.

In your example, you could start with something along the lines of:

```
C2: =if(d2=0,e2/52,d2*30.5/7)
D2: =if(c2=0,e2/12,c2*7/30.5)
E2: =if(c2=0,d2*12,c2*52)
```

I think it would be much neater to repeat the 3 columns, using the first set purely as input, and the second set as output. You could use the same formulas as above, but in cells F2, G2, and H2 instead.